# Mapbox offline region - cannot view the saved map area

Tags: android, mapbox, offline

From version 4.0.0 Mapbox introduced the [ability to download offline regions](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/) to their Android SDK. I'm trying to make use of this functionality in the following way:

1. Download the visible part of the map as an offline region when I am online,
2. Close the app,
3. A few days later and without network connectivity, open the app with the map pointing somewhere in that region and have the map available.

But it doesn't seem to work that way. When I run the app offline, it hangs and there's just grey surface where the map should be. The logs indicate that Mapbox keeps trying to issue requests for map tiles (which it shouldn't, because the map should be available offline).

A quick debug revealed that the map's onMapReadyCallback never gets called, and that's where I tell Mapbox that it should track the user (which brings me to the saved area of the map). So it seems that there's a vicious circle here: I can't go to the saved area if the map's not ready, and the map's not ready until it loads all currently visible tiles, which it can't, because it's offline...

Can anyone help with that?

---

For reference, here's how I download the regions:

```
private void downloadWithinBounds() {
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            Projection projection = mapboxMap.getProjection();
            LatLng topLeft = projection.fromScreenLocation(new PointF(0, 0));
            LatLng bottomRight = projection.fromScreenLocation(
                    new PointF(mapView.getWidth(), mapView.getHeight()));
            manager.createOfflineRegion(new OfflineTilePyramidRegionDefinition(
                    Style.MAPBOX_STREETS,
                    new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                            .include(topLeft)
                            .include(bottomRight)
                            .build(),
                    mapboxMap.getCameraPosition().zoom,
                    mapboxMap.getMaxZoom(),
                    1.0f
            ), new byte[0], new OfflineManager.CreateOfflineRegionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(OfflineRegion offlineRegion) {
                    offlineRegion.setDownloadState(OfflineRegion.STATE_ACTIVE);
                    offlineRegion.setObserver(new OfflineRegion.OfflineRegionObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStatusChanged(OfflineRegionStatus status) {
                            if (status.isComplete()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done saving map.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        // ...

                    });
                }

                // ...

            });
        }
    });
}
```

and here's how I attempt to move the map to the right place in onCreate():

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location last = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        mapboxMap.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .zoom(INITIAL_ZOOM)
                .target(last != null ? new LatLng(last.getLatitude(), last.getLongitude()) : null)
                .build()
        );
        mapboxMap.getTrackingSettings().setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW);
        mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);

        // ...
    }
});
```

The onMapReady() never gets called.

---

EDIT: Here's [the full source code of my activity](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/17b39b55c48f0bb0944b634307fd4b41).

Answer (score 0):

we are currently working on a fix for this issue, you can see if using `4.0.1-SNAPSHOT` will fix the problem. You can do this by opening the apps `build.grade` and using this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. As for `4.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, I've just checked and it doesn't help - the map is hanging as before. Will keep my fingers crossed for you to fix this soon. :)

Comment: Using `4.0.0` and `4.0.1`, I wasn't able to produce the same error using your code snippets. Could you possibly edit your question with any additional code if any. If the issue persist on your end, it might also be a good idea to open an issue on the [mapbox-gl-native repo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues) for more eyes.

Comment: I added the full source of the activity to the question, hope it helps reproduce the issue I'm having.

Comment: Hmmm. Something weird happened. I tried once again on `4.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and it magically worked. By worked I mean that the map doesn't hang anymore, but it's still gray, as if it didn't acknowledge the presence of the saved area...

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your issue. You can view the code I used for this [here](https://gist.github.com/tobrun/9f9f88f6bd150fc94e0eb2cf9c39e49d). In this example I'm setting my camera position in xml pointing at Dalvik in Iceland (65.970773,-18.532800). In the OnMapReady callback I'm trying to download the region if none are available on the device. I leave the device open and wait for the download to finish. When finished I force close the app and turn off wifi/cellular network. 
When I reopen the map no map seems to be loaded.

I tried stepping through your code and noticed this block:

```
    LatLng topLeft = projection.fromScreenLocation(new PointF(0, 0));
    LatLng bottomRight = projection.fromScreenLocation(
            new PointF(mMapView.getWidth(), mMapView.getHeight()));

    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
            .include(topLeft)
            .include(bottomRight)
            .build();
```

I'm seeing that the topLeft and bottomRight are the same LatLng because `mMapView.getWidth()` & `mMapView.getHeight` aren't measured yet and are returning 0 respectivly. Replacing these with hardcoded LatLng from around the Dalvik region solves this for me and the map is loaded.
The code which I was able to make it work is found [here](https://gist.github.com/tobrun/1f0c1d2018d346db69b8551e1acb950e).

Comment: The difference between my code and yours is that you're trying to download the map soon after the activity is created (there are a few threads in between, but the download is basically launched inside `onCreate()`). I am running the download process as a user action, when the map is already visible to the user (the idea behind it is to allow the user to save the area they're viewing on the map for offline). So in my case, `mMapView.getWidth()` & `mMapView.getHeight()` are non-zero.

Comment: I added the full source of the activity to the question, hope it helps reproduce the issue I'm having.